# Придумать алгоритм для задачи: Найти шарики в коробке

Tags: алгоритм

Имеется 50 пронумерованных (от 1 до 50) бесцветных шариков.

Имеется 5 бесцветных пустых коробок.

Часть шариков в случайном порядке раскладываются по 5 коробкам. Например, 40 шариков положили в коробки. При этом ни одна коробка не может быть пустой (т.е. минимум один шарик в коробке). Соответственно, часть шариков остается вне коробок. Вы не знаете в какой именно коробке какой шарик лежит. Также не знаете какие шарики остались вне коробок. Все 50 шариков могут попасть в коробки и ни одного не остаться вне коробок.

Вы можете менять шарикам цвет в любом порядке и любое количество раз. Если все шарики в одной из коробок станут одного цвета, то коробка станет такого-же цвета. Если хотя бы один шарик в коробке имеет отличный цвет (или не имеет цвета), то коробка снова станет бесцветной.

Имея эту возможность идентификации по цвету нужно найти в какой коробке какие лежат шарики (например, в коробке 1 лежат шарики с номерами 10, 7, 23, 50; в коробке 2 лежит шарик с номером 3 и т.д.) и какие шарики не попали ни в одну коробку.

Comment: первое что приходит в голову, это искать признаки, которые подходят ко всем числам, кроме того, которое мы ищем. Тогда незакрашенный ящик будет хранить нужное нам число

Comment: _Вы можете менять шарикам цвет в любом порядке и любое количество раз_ правильно понимаю, что можно сказать "закрась все четные шарики в синий" и это будет норм?

Comment: ThisMan, да можно красить все четные в синий - это норм

Comment: Покрасить все шарики в какой-то один цвет  - все коробки станут этого цвета. и по одному перекрашивать в другой цвет, где перекрасится коробка там и шарик...?

Comment: ++^ таким образом понадобится 100 окрашиваний, или 2*N (где N — число шариков), т. е. линейная от числа шариков сложность. Вас это устроит?

Comment: Stranger in the Q, на самом деле я не знаю решения) Но звучит подходяще

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно окрасить все шарики в какой-то один цвет - все коробки станут этого цвета. и по одному перекрашивать в другой цвет, где перекрасится коробка там и шарик...

Вот сниппет, это не алгоритм а визуализация, если навести на коробку появится тултип - какие там шары ...

```js
let boxes = [[],[],[],[]];

let balls = Array(50).fill(0).map((e, i) => {
  let ball = {index:i};
  Math.random()>0.6 && boxes[Math.floor(Math.random()*boxes.length)].push(ball);
  buttons.innerHTML += `<button id="b${i}" onclick="test(this)">${i+1}</button>${(i+1)%10?'':'<br>'}`
  return ball;
});

boxes.forEach((b,i) => {
  boxesDiv.innerHTML += `<div id="box${i}" title="${b.map(b=>b.index+1)}">${i+1}</div>`
})

function test(el){
  // задаем цвет всех шаров - красный
  balls.forEach(b => b.color = '#faa');
  // задаем цвет шара по индексу нажатой кнопки - синий
  balls[+el.id.substring(1)].color="#aaf";
  // красим кнопки в соответствии цветам шаров
  balls.forEach((b, i) => document.querySelector(`#b${i}`).style.backgroundColor = b.color)
  // красим коробки в зависимости от того какие в них шары
  boxes.forEach((box, i) => document.querySelector(`#box${i}`).style.backgroundColor = box.filter(b => b.color !== '#faa').length ? 'white' : '#faa')
}
```

```css
button{width:30px}
#boxesDiv div{
  display:inline-block;
  width:40px;
  border: solid;
  margin:10px;
  padding:5px;
  text-align:center;
  cursor:default;
}
```

```html
<div id="boxesDiv"></div>
<div id="buttons"></div>
```

Comment: теперь думаем, можно ли сделать это быстрее чем за линейное время)